# iOS 8 Messages To Token Field?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, message

How do I build a token text field like that of the iOS 8 Messages app that allows you to tokenize one or more words so that you can select, copy, and cut one or more of them at a time?

Note: I've seen open source projects like this, but they work the old way, which only allows one token to be selected at a time.

[image: New iMessage]

Comment: Try VENTokenField https://github.com/venmo/VENTokenField

Comment: Nice, but that only allows one token to be selected at a time. I also want it written in Swift.

Comment: The best might be to start writing your own ;)

Comment: @Legoless I've already started. :-)

Comment: Hi! Did you find something?

Comment: No, and I stopped working on my own implementation. Let us know if you build an implementation and open source it or figure something out. Thanks! :-)