# How to inspect the UI of native iOS apps?

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, jailbreak

How can I inspect the UI of the [iOS 8 Messages To Token Field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000943/ios-8-messages-to-text-field)

Comment: What did you figure out about this?

Answer (score 2):

Jailbreak + [FLEX](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX). It's a magical combination.