# Swift Framework Prefix?

Tags: ios, swift, class, uikit, naming

I'm building a Cocoa Touch Framework in Swift to create a UI component like the [iOS Messages "To" Token Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000943/ios-8-messages-to-token-field).

1. What should I name the framework?
2. What should I name the class?

I'm thinking of naming them both the same, but I'm not sure if I should add a prefix.

Some ideas are:

- `UITokenTextView` (standard prefix)
- `ACTokenTextView` (custom prefix)
- `TokenTextView` (no prefix)

I'm considering naming it `UITokenTextView`, but could that cause conflicts if in the future, Apple introduces a class with the same name?

Also, why not just call it `TokenTextView`? That is, [why has Apple kept the UI class prefix in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704475/why-is-apple-keeping-the-ui-class-prefix-in-swift)

Comment: Note: I asked a related question about adding a [Swift class prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214863/swift-class-prefix-needed), but this is about naming a Cocoa Touch Framework and about naming a class (in said framework) that could have the same name as a future class introduced by Apple's UIKit.

Comment: The Swift team either (a) want to keep them consistent with ObjC, these are ObjC classes after all; or (b) doesn't have the resource for renaming all these classes. Evidence for the later can be seen in the transition from Swift 2 to 3, where many fundamental data types dropped their `NS` prefix (`NSURL` became `URL`, `NSDateFormatter` became `DateFormatter`, etc.) and converted to `struct` as well

Comment: Class names and library names can be arbitrary. The library name as one of the classes may be the same, but I would not recommend doing this. The library name can not be repeated in cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

You should better check this document:

[Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Class Names Must Be Unique Across an Entire App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW4)

In Objective-C, there's no namespace support and all globals names (including all class names) exist in a flat global space. And prefixes are used as sort of namespace to make your class name unique. So, **Objective-C compatible classes provided by frameworks should have a unique prefix representing your framework**.

And please do not miss this description in Apple's doc.

> You’ll have noticed that Cocoa and Cocoa Touch class names typically start either with NS or UI. **Two-letter** prefixes like these are reserved by Apple for use in framework classes.

You should avoid two-letter prefixes, as all such prefixes are considered to be reserved by Apple. Apple may at any time reject apps which uses two-letter prefix frameworks in the future. (I know some frameworks are still using two-letter prefix, I'm not sure Apple would really rejects them.)

(And Apple uses some three-letter prefixes like `MTL`-, although there are many more two-letter prefixes still available.)

***2. What should I name the class?***

For Swift only classes, *as you like*. But better avoid some names which may conflict with members of Swift Standard Library (or any names you think would be imported into usual apps.)

For Objective-C compatible classes, use proper prefix having three letters at least. You should not use `UI` or `AC`.

***I'm thinking of naming them both the same***

You can choose any name you like as a framework name, but you should better make your module name and any existing type names different. Swift is often confused with type names and module names.

Comment: Always, always prefix your frameworks, even if they are swift only. We had a framework named *SharedUtils*, and when linking the app with LocalAuthentication it crashed. Turns out the iOS LocalAuthentication framework uses an internal framework called exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if a class has a swift version type, struct or class, it's prefix is dropped, eg: NSData vs Data, or the prefix is kept.

In other way, the Data and NSData are different types, not just drop the NS prefix.